# Blank screen after locking screen

Tags: xubuntu, screen, 15.04, lock-screen

I just updated my Xubuntu 14.10 desktop to 15.04 and I'm having the following issue:

When I lock my computer (or when the inactivity timer locks it for me), the screen goes blank and I cannot get into my session.  The power light on the monitor is still green which means that the monitor hasn't gone to sleep - i.e. that there is still a video signal but no picture is being sent.  The only way to get back into the desktop environment is to switch to a text terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and reboot.

I found a known issue about black screens [after boot](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-346/+bug/1447356), but that's not my problem.

I searched through the syslog, but could not find any messages that seem to be related.

I have all the latest packages available via `apt-get upgrade`.

How can I troubleshoot and fix this issue?

Comment: I also just discovered that I can shorten the wait time by only doing `sudo killall Xorg` instead of a full reboot, but that still doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: please [edit] that comment in.

Comment: @Tim as far as I'm concerned, it's inconsequential; just a shortcut to not need a full reboot.

Comment: Check your screensaver settings. I has this in Kubuntu and resetting the screensaver to something fixed the lock screen for me.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Disabling and reenabling the screen locker has fixed the problem.  If you write your comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. (stupid character requirement)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by going into Light Locker Settings (not sure what it's called: I'm in Windows) and resetting the lockscreen option (turning it off then on again).

Comment: In Xubuntu 14.04, it's called "Light Locker Settings", and all you have to do is turn it off and on again.

Comment: For me, resetting the lock screen option did not work. I installed the "xscreensaver" from software center and it solved the problem.

Comment: Looks like this is what described on the Xubuntu website: https://xubuntu.org/news/laptop-users-fix-available-for-the-black-screen-on-unlock-bug/
I just had the same issue on a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 18.04 (which uses Xfce). Interestingly, I had to first install the Light Locker Settings application from Software, and even though it said "Your screensaver settings are managed by Xfce Power Manager", turning "Enable light-locker" off and then on did fix it.